# Remove Rows Prior to a Condition in SQL

Tags: sql

My simplified SQL table has 3 columns:

Series_Group
Series_Index
Series_Value

For each group, I have a range of series values which may include 0. I only want values after the last 0. So I want to make a query like:
For each group, find the index where a zero occurred, then remove all rows in that group with earlier indexes.

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Group | Index | Value |
+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |     1 |
|     1 |     2 |     0 |
|     1 |     3 |     1 |
|     1 |     4 |     0 |
|     1 |     5 |     6 |
|     2 |     1 |     1 |
|     2 |     2 |     0 |
|     2 |     3 |     1 |
|     2 |     4 |     5 |
|     3 |     1 |     5 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I should only keep

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Group | Index | Value |
+-------+-------+-------+
|     1 |     5 |     6 |
|     2 |     3 |     1 |
|     2 |     4 |     5 |
|     3 |     1 |     5 |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: why rows from group 2 show, if none has `Value = 0` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it using `union all`.

The first part gets all the subsequent rows where there is atleast one value = 0 per group.

The second part gets you all the groups where there are no 0's in the value per group.

[Sample demo](http://rextester.com/XDN15090)

```
select t.* 
from tablename t
join (select grp,max(index) as mxindex from tablename where value = 0 group by grp) t1 
on t.grp = t1.grp and t.index > t1.mxindex
union all
select * from tablename 
where grp in (select grp from tablename group by grp having sum(case when value = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like that

```
select *
from table as a
where index > coalesce((select max(index)
    from table as b
    where a.group=b.group and b.value=0),-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `not exists`:

```
select * from table t1
where value <> 0 and not exists(select * from table t2 
                                where t1.group = t2.group and 
                                      t2.index > t1.index and
                                      t2.value = 0)
```

Comment: Im not sure about the group filter... OP say output include rows from `group = 2 ` and not 0 there

Comment: This query should return required rows. He mensioned `for each group`.

Comment: Sorry but doesnt looks  like the correct result. http://i.stack.imgur.com/qOXns.png

Comment: I really dont see any typo. So here I leave you the sample I try online in case you want fix it and include it in your answer.  http://rextester.com/GPN7115

Comment: In correlated sub query you need check for group = group instead of value = value!

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server. You can use `row_number` to create a `row_id`.

**[SQL Demo](http://rextester.com/FRCV17945)**

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT [group], 
                [index], 
                [value], 
                ROW_NUMBER() 
                  OVER (ORDER BY [group], [index]) AS rn 
         FROM   table1), 
     last_zero 
     AS (SELECT Max(rn) rn 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  [value] = 0) 
SELECT c.[group], 
       C.[index], 
       C.[value] 
FROM   cte C 
       CROSS JOIN last_zero L 
WHERE  C.rn > L.rn
```

Comment: I tried your code and while it works on the sample data I originally provided, it doesn't do it for each "group". I made a small modification to the data (in my question) and the code wouldn't return the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, you question wasnt clear. I didnt understand if you need every row after 0 but inside the group ... or in my case the rest of rows. I recommend you try @vkp solution.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Juan Carlos Oropeza's solution, but without CTE

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ([Group] INT, [Index] INT, [Value] INT)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES  ( 1,1,1)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES  ( 1,2,0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES  ( 1,3,1)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES  ( 1,4,0)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES  ( 1,5,6)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES  ( 2,1,1)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES  ( 2,2,5)

SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Group], [Index]) AS RowNum, * 
  FROM @t
) AS t1
JOIN
(
  SELECT MAX(t3.RowNum) AS MaxRow, t3.[Group]
  FROM
  (  
    SELECT t2.RowNum, t2.[Group] FROM
    (  
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Group], [Index]) AS RowNum, * 
        FROM @t
    ) AS t2 
    WHERE t2.Value = 0
  ) AS t3
  GROUP BY t3.[Group]
) AS t4 ON t1.[Group] = t4.[Group] AND t4.MaxRow < t1.RowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
select t.* from Table1 t
left outer join (    
  select [Group], 
  max(case when [Value] = 0 then [Index] else 0 end) zero_index
  from Table1
  group by [Group]
) a
on t.[Group] = a.[Group]
where t.[Index] > a.zero_index;
```